# WebAuthenticationBroker generated webview doesn't contain close/back buttons

Tags: wpf, windows, uwp

I've been using the WebAuthenticationBroker to connect to external APIs (Onedrive and Google drive); however after porting my app to UWP. The webView that is displayed on tablet mode shows up without a back or a cancel button. (The same webView on phones and in desktop mode appear fine) The hardware back button doesn't seem to work either and am stuck in limbo!

```
 WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None,  new Uri(url),  new Uri(redirectUrl));
```

What could I be doing wrong?[image]